# Programming with a Sporadic Shift Key

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source

There's something wrong with your keyboard. The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key has a mind of its own. Every time you type a character you have no idea whether it will come out shifted or not (though it is 50-50). Besides the standard character keys, nothing on the keyboard is functional. There is no mouse or other means of input.

Somehow you know the only way to fix things is to write a program that outputs `Dear Computer, please stop giving me shift!` to stdout. Luckily your IDE is open and you are capable of running a program, but of course as you type it you won't know which characters will be shifted.

*What sequence of key-presses would you use to write a program that has the best possible chance of working on the first try?*

## Details

You are using a [standard QWERTY keyboard](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Qwerty.svg), so there are 50 character keys you can press.

Unshifted versions (47 only):

```
`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./
```

Shifted versions (47 only):

```
~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}|ASDFGHJKL:"ZXCVBNM<>?
```

The last 3 keys are <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and <kbd>Space</kbd>, which are the same shifted and unshifted.

A sequence of N of these characters has 2<sup>N - (whitespace char count)</sup> ways it might have been output if you had typed them with your faulty keyboard. For example, typing <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> might have yielded
`a m` or `A m` or `a M` or `A M`.

Write a program these characters and look at all of its 2<sup>N - (whitespace char count)</sup> possible shift combinations. The more combinations that output `Dear Computer, please stop giving me shift!` the better. Your score is the number of working combinations (valid programs) divided by the total number of combinations. The highest score wins.

## Notes

- For valid programs, printing precisely `Dear Computer, please stop giving me shift!` and nothing else to stdout should be the only side effect.
- Valid programs should not take input.
- Invalid programs can do anything whatsoever.
- Comments may be used anywhere.
- [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)) answers cannot win because getting a 100% score is (relatively) trivial. You may still submit a Whitespace solution for fun.
- Your program must be at most 1024 characters long.

***Update:* Changed `Stop giving me shift!` to `Dear Computer, please stop giving me shift!` to allow for more complex answers. Existing answers may stay the way they are if desired.**

Comment: Why's the 1024-character restriction?

Comment: @JanDvorak Without a limit there might be ways to make the limit of valid programs approach 100% as the size of the program increases. (Though that would be pretty cool.)

Comment: I can't think of any way to improve the baseline score of 2^-(18 + whatever the language needs)

Comment: Please ping me once there is a better answer than mine

Comment: @JanDvorak Without the restriction, you could do something like  `exec(min(["code","code","code",...]))`, with a ginormous number of copies of your code to run a lower-cased version of it basically guaranteed.

Comment: +1, it's a great challenge, but I wish you'd given us a longer output string. I've thought of several clever tricks, but all of them take more than 18 characters in all the languages I know.

Comment: @Nathaniel I was just wishing that too,. It's only been an hour, I may change it.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies but... what about the current answers?

Comment: @xnor the problem with your suggestion is that each pair quotes is a 2^-1 to your score and so are the commas inbetween. Unless you do something like `.words`

Comment: I have changed the phrase. Existing answers can stay, though not a ton may need to change in them. Apologies for rule change. (@Nathaniel)

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Now the score becomes a non standard as the previous string will always result in a lower score. Can you either switch back to older string or mandate the use of new one ?

Comment: @Optimizer Sorry but it would be unfair to the original answers to force the change. All new answers must use the new string through, and it may be possible to beat the best old answer.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies It's not! And the 1024 limitation prevents that very well too. given all this, I am voting for this to close as unclear what you are asking. Please do not change spec which gives disadvantage to most of the answers

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Too bad there's the 1024 char limit. I'm going to need to rethink my answer...

Comment: @Optimizer I have removed the 2^-7 one in the answer. So there isn't much trouble now.

Comment: @user23013 There are other answers based on the previous string too.

Comment: @Optimizer At least they won't win.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not allowed or able to hold down the other shift key to force everything shifted?  Or would doing so give you a 75% chance of being shifted and 25% of unshifted if both of your shift keys act identical?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones No. Assume pressing either shift does nothing. The computer just thinks shift is being pressed randomly.

Comment: For once in my life, knowledge of VB is more useful than knowledge of C++.

Comment: A perfect time to use [WhiteSpace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29)?

Comment: @awashburn That's not allowed (for winning). See rules.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Applescript, 2<sup>0</sup> (100%)

I believe I can claim a perfect score here:

- The Applescript Editor (my IDE) automatically converts all keywords to lower case upon compiling/running
- Furthermore, defined variable and handler names are case insensitive - For example if a handler `myFunc` is defined, then the IDE will automatically convert `MYFUNC`, `myfunc`, `MyFuNc`, etc references to `myFunc`
- I have only used alphabetic characters, spaces and newlines, so I don't need to worry about shifted numbers and punctuation characters.

Here is is:

```
global f
on j at a
set end of a to j
end
on c at a
j at a
j at a
end
on k at a
repeat with q in system info
j at a
end
end
on w at a
set d to count a
j at a
return string id d
end
on z at a
set end of f to a
end
set h to space
set y to h as list
k at y
k at y
set x to w at y
c at y
c at y
c at y
c at y
c at y
set q to w at y
k at y
c at y
c at y
copy y to b
c at y
set s to w at y
set d to w at y
set f to d as list
k at b
k at b
set a to w at b
c at b
j at b
set e to w at b
set y to w at b
set g to w at b
set d to w at b
set i to w at b
c at b
set l to w at b
set m to w at b
set n to w at b
set o to w at b
set p to w at b
j at b
set r to w at b
z at e
z at a
z at r
z at h
z at s
set s to w at b
set t to w at b
set u to w at b
set v to w at b
z at o
z at m
z at p
z at u
z at t
z at e
z at r
z at q
z at h
z at p
z at l
z at e
z at a
z at s
z at e
z at h
z at s
z at t
z at o
z at p
z at h
z at g
z at i
z at v
z at i
z at n
z at g
z at h
z at m
z at e
z at h
z at s
z at d
z at i
z at y
z at t
z at x
f as text
```

Thanks to the help of @kernigh and @paradigmsort, this is now 1020 bytes, just squeaking in under the 1024 byte limit!

#### Explanation:

- The characters for output string are generated using `string id <n>`, which returns the character corresponding to the ascii value `n`
- Because we are avoiding digits, each `n` has has to be generated by more fundamental means.  Specifically we generate each `n` by counting a list, and then adding another item to that list.  The `repeat with q in system info` allows us to do this 16 times, as `system info` always returns a 16-item list.
- Using a similar technique, we add each character of the final string in turn to a list.
- Finally that last list is coerced to `text` and printed.

#### Output:

Using the `osascript` interpreter, but the Applescript Editor works just as well:

```
$ # Interpret as-is:
$ osascript dearcase.scpt
Dear Computer, please stop giving me shift!
$ 
$ # Interpret all lower case:
$ tr A-Z a-z < dearcase.scpt | osascript
Dear Computer, please stop giving me shift!
$ 
$ # Interpret all upper case:
$ tr a-z A-Z < dearcase.scpt | osascript
Dear Computer, please stop giving me shift!
$
$ # Interpret random case for each letter:
$ while read; do for ((i=0;i<${#REPLY};i++)); do c="${REPLY:i:1}"; if ((RANDOM%2)); then printf "%s" "$(tr a-z A-Z <<< "$c")"; else printf "%s" "$(tr A-Z a-z <<< "$c")"; fi; done; echo; done < dearcase.scpt | osascript
Dear Computer, please stop giving me shift!
$
```

Comment: Very very cool! I hope you can get it to 1024. Mind explaining the code a bit?

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Applescript is supposed to be one of the most readable languages - you really don't understand this? ;-)  I'll try to add an explanation in a bit...

Comment: Please post the golfed version, with no indentation and no name in `end name`. As is, I must use `sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/^end.*/end/' dearcase.scpt | wc -c` to count it.  Also, you can get down from 1044 to 1037 by changing `count of a` to `count a`, and deleting `log` from `log f as text`.  I test with an old OS X 10.4 system, where `log` command has empty result; `osascript` only prints the result, not the event log, so I get no output unless I delete `log`.

Comment: Changing c to call j twice instead of three times and updating the call sites as needed saves 7 characters and gets you under the limit.

Comment: `# Interpret all upper case:
$ tr A-Z a-z` - The args are backwards, right?

Comment: @Izkata Yes, copy/paste error - good catch.

Answer (score 16):

## PHP, 2^-12

```php
echo ucwords(strtolower('Dear Computer, ')).strtolower('please stop giving me shift!');
```

PHP being PHP, capitalization of `echo`, `ucwords`, and `strtolower` don't matter. The calls to `ucwords` and `strtolower` ensure that the case of the strings won't change the output.

Therefore, the only characters that can't be changed are `((,)).(!);` (10 characters).

Each pair of quotes also has a 50% chance of being valid (`''` and `""` are valid, but `'"` and `"'` are not), therefore each adding another power of two.

Comment: @edc65 `ucwords` capitalizes the first letter of each word

Comment: a good IDE will add the correct closing quotes for you (you'll only ever end up with `''` or `""`, as well as the closing parentheses, so though you still have a 50% chance for `(`, the `)` should be automatic.

Comment: shoot, you can't use any sort of navigation keys (arrows), so even if your IDE did autocomplete correctly, you'd need to type that same character again or else it will insert the new (wrong) one, like this: `strtolower("Dear Computer, '"0)`...

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I believe relying on IDE features would be counted as cheating.

Comment: What about `<?` at the start of the program?

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <strike>2<sup>-7</sup></strike> 2<sup>-12</sup> chance

```
'D"ear Komputer, please stop giving me shift!"el4'Ct
```

It has similar idea as [Quincunx's first answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39955/), but in CJam.

Comment: Is this intentionally a `K` instead of `C`?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann That character is independent. It can also be a space or something else.

Answer (score 4):

## Whitespace (645 bytes, 2^0 probability)

Since this program *only* uses tabs, spaces and newlines (which are all unaffected by shifting), it gives a 100% success rate.

[Program run](http://ideone.com/aEvmfj)

Comment: But note that this is off-competition as per the rules.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 2<sup>-20</sup> chance

```python
print'S'+'top giving me shift!'.lower()
```

`print`, `S`, `+`, `!`, and `.lower()` must all be the correct version; that's 18 chars. The two quotes for the strings must also align, that makes two more powers of two.

For any of the `top giving me shift`, if it is converted to the capital version, we convert it to lowercase and it works properly.

Sadly, I can't make use of Python's nifty `capitalize()`, because that takes one more character.

Comment: If it helps, the phrase is now longer (but not capitalized normally).

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies I saw that. It doesn't help; it harms.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 2<sup>-9</sup> chance, [739 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%22%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%20%20%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%0A%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%0A%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%20%09%09%0A%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%0A%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%0A%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%0A%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%0A%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%0A%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%0A%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%20%20%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%0A%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%0A%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%0A%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%0A%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%0A%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%20%09%09%09%09%0A%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%0A%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%0A%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%0A%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%20%09%09%09%09%20%0A%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%20%09%09%09%09%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%0A%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%0A%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%20%20%20%0A%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%20%20%09%0A%09%09%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%20%09%09%20%0A%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%0A%09%09%20%09%09%09%09%20%09%20%20%09%09%20%20%09%22N%2F2fb%3Ac)

```
"                         
(lines of space characters)
                                        "N/2fb:c
```

base64:

```
IiAJICAgIAkgCQkgICAJICAKICAgCSAJCSAgIAkJCQkgCQoJCQkJIAkgIAkJIAkJICAJCiAJICAg
IAkgCQkgICAgCSAKICAgCSAJCSAgCSAgICAgIAogCQkJCSAJICAJCSAJIAkJCgkJCSAJICAJCSAJ
CSAJCQkKIAkgCQkgIAkgICAgIAkgCQoJIAkJICAJICAgIAkgICAgCgkgIAkJIAkJCQkgIAkJIAkK
CQkgCSAgCQkgCQkJIAkgIAogICAJIAkJICAgCQkJCSAJCiAJICAgIAkgCQkgICAgCSAKIAkJCQkg
CSAgCQkgCQkgIAogICAJIAkJICAJICAgICAgCgkgCQkgIAkgICAgCSAgICAKCSAgCSAgICAJIAkg
CQkgIAogICAJIAkJICAgCQkJCSAJCgkJCQkgCSAgCQkgCQkgIAkKICAgIAkgCQkgICAJCSAJCQog
ICAJIAkJICAgCQkJCSAJCiAgIAkgCQkgIAkgICAgICAKICAgIAkgCQkgICAJCSAJCQoJCSAJICAJ
CSAJCQkgCSAgCgkJCSAJICAJCSAJCSAJCQkKCSAJCSAgCSAgICAJICAgIAogICAJIAkJICAJICAg
ICAgCgkgCSAgCQkgCQkJIAkJCQkKICAJCSAJCQkJIAkgICAgCQogCQkgIAkgICAgCSAgCQkgCiAg
CQkgCQkJCSAJICAgIAkKICAJICAgIAkgCSAJCQkJIAoJIAkgIAkJIAkJCSAJCQkJCiAgIAkgCQkg
IAkgICAgICAKIAkgCQkgIAkgICAgIAkgCQogICAJIAkJICAgCQkJCSAJCiAgIAkgCQkgIAkgICAg
ICAKICAgIAkgCQkgICAJCSAJCQogCQkgCQkJCSAJICAJICAgCiAgCQkgCQkJCSAJICAgIAkKCQkg
CQkJCSAJICAJIAkJIAoJCSAJICAJCSAJCQkgCSAgCgkJIAkJCQkgCSAgCQkgIAkiTi8yZmI6Yw==
```

Based on the idea of Optimizer and Quincunx's answer.

Answer (score 2):

## VisualBasic.net 2^-18

Critical chars: .("DearC"+",!".())

```
Sub Main
  console.write("Dear C"+"omputer, please stop giving me shift!".tolower())
End Sub
```

Tested in LINQPad, Language = "VB Program"

Comment: I think visual studio would auto-correct the casing for you.

Comment: @Pharap but the casing outside quotes is not the problem... VS would not correct a '(' shifted to '9'

Comment: In that case, something more useful: you can get rid of the potential case of getting `>` instead of `.` by changing `Console.Write(string)` to `Write(string)` and swapping `(string).ToLower()` out for `LCase(string)`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 2**-15

```
+"S"$"top giving me shift!".lower()
```

I can't seem to find Pyth's version of `lower()`, so I'll borrow from Python. The characters that can't be swapped are `+"S"$`, `!`, and `.lower()`, for a total of 14 chars. The quotes after the `$` must match, adding another power of 2.

Comment: Pyth doesn't have a `lower()` - it wasn't getting used enough. I should probably add it back in.

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 2<sup>-13</sup> chance

As per the updated string ([696](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%22%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22N%2F%3A%2C2%2FKfb%3Ac) bytes).

```
"   




















































































             "N/:,2/Kfb:c
```

Only `""N/:,2/Kfb:c` are at risk right now.

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) and since this text editor is eating up all the spaces, here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/scrapmac/0b2057a2211e2c25fde0) with the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

## Rant, 2<sup>-21</sup>

```
[caps:first][?[caps:word][?[caps:lower]Dear Computer][caps:lower], please stop giving me shift!]
```

A series of metapatterns and `caps` calls force proper formatting. Function names and arguments are case insensitive.

[Online version](http://berkin.me/rantbox#3DE47998427FD034A1942F449E237163585C58AE)

Answer (score 1):

### VB.NET, <s>2^-12</s> 2^-11

**2<sup>-12</sup>**

```
Module All
  Sub Main 
    Console.WriteLine StrConv("Dear Computer, ", vbTuesday) & "please stop giving me shift!".ToLower
  End Sub
End Module
```

**2<sup>-11</sup>**

```
Imports System.Console

Module All
  Sub Main 
    Write StrConv("Dear Computer, ", vbTuesday)
    WriteLine "please stop giving me shift!".ToLower
  End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought about my answer before getting to the '50 characters including only Enter, Tab, Space' rule. So mine is not valid.

Seems having case insensitive programming languages is the key here. Alternatively, if you could use a Real standard QWERTY keyboard (including Caps Lock, the other Shift, Backspace, and the Numpad Period) there would only be 2 necessary 50% chances which would only result in 2 additional key presses per failure. My invalid answer for a C# Console Application pointing out actual key presses:

```
HoldShift(C CpsLockOn onsole)

NumPadPeriod

HoldShift(
CpsLockOff W CpsLockOn rite(" 
CpsLockOff D CpsLockOn ear space
CpsLockOff C CpsLockOn omputer
)

, (repeat with Backspace until correct)

HoldShift( please stop giving me shift!"))

; (repeat with Backspace until correct)
```

---

76 minimum presses with only 2 necessary 50% chances

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 2<sup>-11</sup>

```
=PROPER("Dear Computer, ")&LOWER("please stop giving me shift!")
```

Case of `PROPER` and `LOWER` don't matter.
Entering a formula starting with `+` automatically inserts required `=`.
So only `(`, `"`, `,`, `)`, `&`, `!` can break.