# Convert C header names to C++ header names

Tags: code-golf, string, conversion

In the C standard library, header names end with a `.h` suffix:

```
stdio.h
```

In C++, those header names are available in an alternative form, with a `c` prefix instead:

```
cstdio
```

Write a function that converts the first form into the second. You can do the conversion in-place, or leave the original string intact and return a new string. Whatever feelds natural in your language of choice.

The code must be compiled/interpreted without errors. Compiler warnings are acceptable.

Here is your baseline C solution. It has **70 characters** and generates a warning about `strlen`:

```
void f(char*h){int i=strlen(h);h[--i]=0;while(--i)h[i]=h[i-1];*h='c';}
```

The shortest solution (measured in number of characters) wins.

**Update:** If your language of choice does not support functions, whole programs are also acceptable.

**Update:** As suggested by FUZxxl, here is a complete list of the header files in the C standard library:

```
assert.h
ctype.h
errno.h
float.h
limits.h
locale.h
math.h
setjmp.h
signal.h
stdarg.h
stddef.h
stdio.h
stdlib.h
string.h
time.h
```

Specifically, there are no header names with multiple dots in them.

Answer (score 37):

## 80386 machine code, 13 bytes

Hexdump of the code:

```
b0 63 86 01 41 3c 2e 75 f9 c6 01 00 c3
```

Source code (can be compiled by Visual Studio):

```
__declspec(naked) void __fastcall conv(char s[])
{
    _asm {
        mov al, 'c';            // b0 63
    myloop:
        xchg al, [ecx];         // 86 01
        inc ecx;                // 41
        cmp al, '.';            // 3c 2e
        jne myloop;             // 75 f9
        mov byte ptr [ecx], 0;  // c6 01 00
        ret;                    // c3
    }
}
```

It converts the string in-place. The code is so simple, it doesn't need to save and restore registers (using only `al` and `ecx`, which the `fastcall` convention allows to clobber).

Comment: Nice, this takes me back :)

Comment: Definitely one of the cooler solutions! But the source code isn't really 13 bytes, only the compiled form of it (that I think few of us would want to write in a hex editor).

Comment: Give him his win. Byte = character is a perfectly reasonable interpretation here.

Comment: @PerLundberg I see the source code in this case as being the "how it works" expanded/commented explanation that a lot of people include in their ultra-compact languages. For such a small program it could very well have been hand-written. :)

Comment: @fluffy Fair point. And yeah, the number of people that could write the binary code by heart is certainly >0, even though I don't know anyone that geeky myself. ;)

Answer (score 14):

## Python: 19 characters

```
lambda s:'c'+s[:-2]
```

Answer (score 14):

## CJam, 6 bytes

```
'clW(<
```

This is a full program which reads the string via STDIN

**Explanation**:

```
'c               "Put character c on stack";
  l              "Read a line from STDIN";
   W             "W is a predefined variable with value -1";
    (            "Decrease the value by 1";
     <           "Remove last 2 characters from the string on stack, the input argument";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='clW(%3C)

Comment: Isn't `-2` just as good as `W(`?

Answer (score 12):

### Java 8 — 25 characters

```
h->"c"+h.replace(".h","")
```

Answer (score 11):

## brainfuck - <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
,[>,]<-----.<,<[<]>[.>]
```

> If your language of choice does not support functions, whole programs are also acceptable.

This is a whole program that takes input from STDIN.

```
,[>,]      get all bytes of input
<-----.    subtract 5 from last byte (always "h"; "h" minus 5 = "c") and print result
<,         set second last byte to 0 by abusing comma
<[<]>      go to first byte
[.>]       print byte and move right until hitting 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't this step off the left edge of the tape upon [<]

Comment: @feersum If your interpreter allows you to step off the left edge, yes. Every one I've ever used loops the tape.

Comment: @feersum If you'd like to try it but your interpreter does allow you to fall off, you can fix it with a `>` at the beginning.

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell — 23 characters

```
('c':).takeWhile(/='.')
```

### Haskell — 16 characters, as suggested by nimi

```
('c':).init.init
```

Comment: Dropping the last 2 characters with `init.init` instead of taking all up to the first `.` saves a few bytes.

Comment: @nimi That is an awesome suggestion!

Answer (score 10):

## C, 38

[See on Ideone](http://ideone.com/hDbAax)

```
f(s,o){snprintf(o,strlen(s),"c%s",s);}
```

`s` is a pointer to the input string, and `o` is where the output should be written to.

I found a way to abuse `snprintf`. The output string conveniently happens to be one character shorter than the input, and the maximum length of the string written by `snprintf` is 1 less than the `n` argument, so it cuts off the `.h`. Note: this technique will not work with Microsoft's implementation because it does the wrong thing and fails to null-terminate the string.

Answer (score 9):

## TIS Node Type T21 Architecture - 85 bytes

**This answer is just for fun; the language came into existence after this challenge was written and I therefore cannot win with it. (Not that I was going to.)**

[image]

Okay, I had a little fun with this one. I probably *should* just call the language "TIS-100", but why break character? :D

TIS-100 is a game about programming a computer with a totally unique and bizarre architecture. I wrote a [custom puzzle](http://pastebin.com/zvnps8JV) for this challenge, which allows me to take input and check output against a known-correct "string". Unfortunately, there's no way to handle strings or characters, so this program simply uses the ASCII value of each character for input and output.

If you'd like to see it in action, you can use [this emulator](http://tise.hansihe.com/), or just watch me run it in the actual game [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBbGYkiKGW4). Note that in the video, the final line of the first node is `D:MOV UP NIL`. After finishing the video, I realized I could golf that down to `D:ADD UP`. Functionally there's no difference, because the value of ACC is immediately overwritten anyway.

This is the string I used for my byte count:

```
MOV 99 ANY
MOV -46 ACC
ADD UP
JEZ D
ADD ACC ANY
JRO -5
D:ADD UP
MOV UP ANY
MOV UP ANY
```

That's the text of each non-empty node, seperated by newlines (effectively adding 1 byte for each node used beyond the first, mirroring our rule about code in multiple files).

Answer (score 8):

**Windows Batch file 11**

```
@echo c%~n1
```

The first parameter passed in is %1.  The ~n modifier returns just the filename without extension.

If it's acceptable to echo the expanded command to the screen as well, then the initial @ could be removed.

Answer (score 7):

### J (9 characters)

```
'c',_2}.]
```

- `|y` is the *magnitude* of `y` (also called absolute value)
- `x }. y` drops `|x` items from `y`; items are dropped from the front if `x` is positive, from the end if `x` is negative.
- `x , y` appends `x` and `y`.
- `'c' , _2 }. y` does the transformation you want; in tacit notation this can be expressed as `'c' , _2 }. ]`.

Answer (score 7):

### Dyalog APL (8 characters)

```
'c',¯2↓⊢
```

This solution is exactly the same as the J solution I submitted but uses one character less due to `↓` being one character less than `}.`.

Answer (score 7):

## piet (<strike>9x11 = 99</strike> 8X11=88)

[image: v2]

### another try (2x37 = 74)

[image]

Hard to make it much smaller since it needs to generate a 99 ('c') and a 46('.'), and that takes space in piet.

Comment: Piet's never measured in characters, only codels, so you don't need to mention the 0 chars bit :) Also that's a lot of white

Comment: trying to compress, but it is a bit difficult. Having trouble getting it to terminate if I remove yet another row or column.

Comment: This is a bit of cheating, but I like it. This is like using `/dev/null` as your source-code.

Comment: According to META (http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4782/do-programs-have-to-terminate?cb=1), your program isn't required to finish. As long as it does it's task, your program can run forever. Read the first answer to the question.

Answer (score 7):

## [Ostrich 0.6.0](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/ostrich-lang/releases/tag/v0.6.0-alpha), 8 characters

```
););"c\+
```

`)` is the "right uncons" operator. When applied to a string, it turns, for example, `` `foo` `` into `` `fo` `o` ``. `;` is used to pop the extra character off, and this is done again.

Then, `"c` is pushed. This is simply a shorthand for `` `c` ``.

`\+` swaps the top two stack elements and concatenates them.

Comment: Was this language created by you?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes. (See [the main Github repo](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/ostrich-lang).)

Comment: I though so. I already checked it, therefore thinking about it. There is no reference on that language anywhere. Only here. So, I assumed it was made by you. For a 14 years old guy, you went really far on programming. +1000 for that!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Whoops, sorry, should have told you that I'm [KeyboardFire](http://github.com/KeyboardFire) on Github. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to. It's almost implied. I'm ismael-miguel (very original, check https://github.com/ismael-miguel). I have nothing interesting and useful there, but you may check it. But I'm interested on your language. The only complete thing is the UIntArray class for php (https://github.com/ismael-miguel/php-uintarray if you are interested).

Answer (score 6):

### F# - <del>39</del> <del>37</del> 31

*31 - Because typeinference in F# rocks!*

```
fun s->("c"+s).Replace(".h","")
```

*37*

```
fun(s:string)->"c"+s.Replace(".h","")
```

*39*

```
fun(s:string)->"c"+s.Remove(s.Length-2)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for a header named foo.hoo.h.

Comment: @FUZxxl There are no such headers in the C standard library.

Comment: @FredOverflow You might want to specify the set of names on which the transformation has to work. Right now your question is worded in a way that might lead people to assume that this kind of input must work correctly.

Comment: @FUZxxl I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

## gema, 6

```
*.h=c*
```

([Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/new/index.shtml) is an obscure macro language.)

Answer (score 5):

## GNU sed -r, 14

sed doesn't really have any concept of functions, so here is a complete sed program instead:

```
s/(.*)../c\1/
```

#### Output

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)../c\1/' <<< stdio.h
cstdio
$
```

The `-r` has been included in the score as one extra character.

Comment: This solution is invalid: It should probably be `s/\(.*\)\.h/c\1/` instead.

Comment: @FUZxxl - I'm assuming `-r` is passed to sed.  As per usual [tag:code-golf] I need to count that as an extra point.

Comment: @DigitalTraume Notice that `-r` is not a standard option and not available outside of GNU sed. You might want to change the language name to GNU sed to reflect that.

Comment: @FUZxxl Yes. Done.

Comment: `\.h` can be shortened to `..`

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Yes - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, 18

```
f()(echo c${1%.*})
```

#### Output:

```
$ f stdio.h
cstdio
$
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 7 characters

```
L+\cPPb
```

Explanation:

```
L         def y(b):return
 +\c                      "c" +
    PPb                         b[:-1][:-1]
```

Try this:

```
L+\cPPb
y"stdio.h
```

on the online [Pyth Compiler/Executor](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

---

If full programs were allowed:

## Pyth, 6 characters

```
+\cPPQ
```

Comment: I have never seen Pyth. Would you be so kind and explain the code? :)

Comment: @FredOverflow See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40039/18487

Comment: I believe you can use `PPb` instead of `<b_2`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks.

Comment: It seems like full programs are allowed, so you can get to 6.

Comment: "If your language of choice does not support functions, whole programs are also acceptable" Pyth defs has functions

Answer (score 3):

## [Prelude](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Prelude), 31 characters

Since full program submissions are apparently acceptable, here is a program that reads the C-style header from STDIN and prints the C++-style header to STDOUT:

```
99+9+(?)###(#
9(1-)       ^)(!)
```

This requires a standard-compliant interpreter which prints output as character codes. If you're using [the Python interpreter](http://web.archive.org/web/20060504072747/http://z3.ca/~lament/prelude.py) you'll need to set `NUMERIC_OUTPUT = False`.

It also requires that there's no trailing newline on STDIN.

### Explanation

In Prelude all lines are executed in parallel, one column at a time. Each line has its own stack, initialised to an infinite amount of `0`s.

```
99+9+
9(1-)
```

This is the shortest I could come up with to get a `99` onto the top stack (the character code of `c`). First I add up `18` on the top stack and push a `9` onto the bottom stack. The bottom then counts down to `0` in a loop, while the top stack adds more `9`s up. This adds up to `99` on the top stack, and the bottom stack is left with `0`s again. Note that all of `+9+` is part of the loop, so there are actually two addition operations per iteration, but that's not an issue, thanks to the infinite supply of `0`s underneath.

Now `(?)` reads STDIN, one character at a time and pushes onto the top stack. The loop terminates at the end of the input, when `?` pushes a zero. `###` gets rid of that zero, the `h` and the `.`. Now the next loop pops numbers from the top stack while copying them to the bottom stack. This essentially reverses the stack. Note that the opening and closing parentheses are on different lines - this is not an issue, because the vertical position of the `)` is irrelevant in Prelude, but it saves me a byte on the first line.

Lastly, `(!)` prints all the characters until the stack is empty.

Answer (score 3):

## C++14, 41 characters

```
[](auto&s){s="c"+s.substr(0,s.size()-2);}
```

Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45698/25315) other answer. I made it a separate answer because here I use a feature that is new in c++14, [generic lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17233547/509868).

See it in action [here](https://ideone.com/bB7F47).

Answer (score 2):

### Perl — 20 characters

```
sub{c.pop=~s/..$//r}
```

Note how `c` is a bareword and as such this requires a lack of `use strict`. This must be used as an expression, not a statement.

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL — 58 characters

```
CREATE PROC Q(@ VARCHAR(MAX))AS
SELECT'c'+LEFT(@,LEN(@)-2)
```

Run as EXEC Q (your string here)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 64

Mildly shorter than the c reference:

```
f(char*h){char*d=strstr(h,".");memmove(h+1,h,d++-h);*d=0;*h=99;}
```

Probably more golfing to be done with this.

---

#### C, 48 (libc hack)

```
f(char*h){strcpy(h+1,h);*strstr(h,".")=0;*h=99;}
```

The `strcpy` manpage explicitly states "The strings may not overlap".  However I found that the libc I am using appears to be coded safely to handle this correctly all the same.  This is GNU C Library (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.4) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Is omitting the return type of a function legal in C89?

Comment: @FredOverflow.  Yes - gcc compiles this just fine with `-std=c89`.  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2204/11259

Comment: @FredOverflow Yes. The return type defaults to `int`.

Comment: The man page just reiterates the Standard - compiling this with VC++ (VS2012) gives "cstdii" for "stdio.h".  Didn't check ICC/Sun/clang, but your 64-char version says "why?" - it's about as short as it can (legally) be in C.

Answer (score 2):

## Marbelous, 24

```
@063
-Z//
3W<C+Z
]]!!
@0
```

Takes input through STDIN, outputs to STDOUT.

This works by checking each byte with `.` (`0x46`). As `0x46` cannot fit inside a single base-36 digit, we subtract 35 (`Z`) before comparing, and add it back before outputting.

Each marble is duplicated by `3W` (three-way duplicator, but the left side is discarded off the side of the board). The marble sent downwards fetches the next byte from STDIN. The marble to the right is checked to `.`, then either outputted, or sent to `!!`, which terminates the program.

The program starts by passing `c` (`0x63`) through, which will be output to STDOUT.

[Try it online here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40808/29611) Libraries must be enabled, cylindrical boards must be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 20

Can't believe ES6 was still missing

```
s=>'c'+s.slice(0,-2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 15 (14 + -p)

```
s/(.*)\.h/c$1/
```

Answer (score 2):

### mk, 34 characters

mk(1) is the Plan 9 replacement for make. Just for fun, this mkfile converts C header names into C++ header names:

```
c%:Q:
    :

%.h:Q: c%
    echo $prereq
```

There is a single tab before `:` and `echo`. Use like this:

```
% mk stdio.h
cstdio
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
\cpṪṪ
```

Explanation:

```
\cpṪṪ   # full program
\c      # c
  p     # prepend using implicit input
   ṪṪ   # remove last two letters
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5Ccp%E1%B9%AA%E1%B9%AA&inputs=stdio.h&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## CoffeeScript - 16

```
(x)->"c"+x[..-3]
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC 83/84, 15

```
"c"+sub(Ans,1,length(Ans)-2
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby: 16 characters

```
->x{?c+x[0..-3]}
```

Or, more correct solution as suggested by @[mbuettner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner)

```
->x{?c+x[/\w+/]}
```

You can call it like this:

```
->x{?c+x[/\w+/]}.call 'stdio.h'
# cstdio
```

Comment: XD damnn.. XD XD

Answer (score 1):

### R, 33

```
function(x)sub("(.+)..","c\\1",x)
```

This function uses regular expressions.

Example usage:

```
> (function(x)sub("(.+)..","c\\1",x))("stdio.h")
[1] "cstdio"
```

Answer (score 1):

## MS QuickBasic or QB64 ~ 33 bytes

```
A$=left$(A$,len(A$)-2)
A$="c"+A$
```

A$ is the name of the file

Answer (score 1):

### Go, <s>47</s>,46

```
func h(s string)string{return"c"+s[:len(s)-2]}
```

I know I'm not winning anything with this, but I thought I might as well go for it. No pun intended

Comment: I think you can drop the space between `return` and `"c"`.

Comment: @FUZxxl I didn't know I could do that, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

## C++ 14, 48

```
[](string s){return "c"+s.substr(0,s.size()-2);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

Since full programs are now allowed...

```
i:0(?v
~}-5~/r
o;!?l<
```

### Explanation

```
i:0(?v      Keep reading input until EOF
~}-5~/r     Pop the -1 from EOF, turn 'h' -> 'c' with 5- and shift to back, pop '.', reverse stack
o;!?l<      Keep outputting until the stack is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 7 bytes

```
"c",-2_
```

Pretty simple. Just drops 2 chars off the end and prepends a `c`.

Also, despite how it looks, this is actually a function:

```
f:"c",-2_
f"stdio.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Awk: 10 characters

```awk
$0="c"$1
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ awk -F. '$0="c"$1' <<< 'stdio.h'
cstdio
```

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 5 bytes

```
éc$xx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///DKZJWKiv//i0tSMvP1MgA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e963 2478 78                             .c$xx
```

This is a full program that takes input from STDIN.

### Explanation

```
éc     insert the character 'c'
$      go to the end of the line
xx     delete two characters
```

This is `ic<esc>$xx` in pure Vim.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel formula, <s>36</s> 23 bytes

If the input is put in cell A1,

```
="c"&LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)
```

#### Explanation

```
="c"&LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)
="c"&                     Return the letter 'c' concatenated with...
     LEFT(            )   the first...
             LEN(A1)-2    (the length of input, minus 2 from the '.h') characters...
          A1,             of the input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¨¨'cì
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##Pc09DsIwDEDhq6AsLAjBwGkQg5u6rVF@KscLA/fpwMrElu69UhCKyfYNT3qnC3RnLNu75CUve7u@yjN/ytVASshynMxhZ6w8ZqxE5hArBxdBA0eeJKmjBae1B5mqEsrdz2oaAzi19MBjc49DM8VGR93fTEFzIf/b3L4)
Header `ε` is used to for-each over the input-list to verify all test cases instead of just one.
Footer `}»` is to close this for-each, and print the results with new-line delimiter.

**Explanation:**

```
¨¨       # Remove the last two characters of the input
    ì    # Prepend:
  'c     #  "c"
```

Comment: Technically not competing since the whole language was made after the question was asked.

Comment: @Nit Not anymore since the Summer of 2017. [Relevant meta post.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges)

Comment: Ah, didn't know that, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```bash
ic ¯-2
ic     # Given the default input, prepend a 'c' at the start
   ¯-2 # and trim off the last two letters.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/PzNZ4dB6XaP//5WKS1Iy8/UylAA)

Comment: Save a byte by omitting the `'`.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks, I often forget Japt handles inputs as defaulting to chars in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 63 bytes

```
[S S S T    T   S S S T T   N
_Push_99_c][T   N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S S S N
S_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_character][T   T   T   _Retrieve][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T T   T   S N
_Push_46_.][T   S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_EXIT][T N
S S _Print_as_character][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZMTTHBxcikoQBAQcykABYCinGC@ApQJVAkSVoCq5eL6/7@4JCUzXy8DAA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Print "c"
Start LOOP
  Character i = STDIN as character
  if(i == '.')
    EXIT program (with error)
  Print i
  Go to next iteration of LOOP
```

Program stops with an error: Label_EXIT not found.

Answer (score 1):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 43 bytes

```
Write 99
N
Count i while _/96 {
Write _
N
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/z@8KLMkVcHSksuPyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXt/STKGaCyIfD5Su/f@/uCQlM18vAwA)

#### Algorithm

- Write `c`
- Read a character into the accumulator
- Loop while that character is a lowercase letter:

  - Write the character
  - Read another character

Answer (score 0):

## TI-89 Basic, 56 bytes

```
:Def a(a)=Func
:Return "c"+sub(a,1,length(a)-2
:End Func
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia: 19 characters

```julia
f(s)="c"*s[1:end-2]
```

Sample run:

```
julia> f(s)="c"*s[1:end-2]
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> print(f("stdio.h"))
cstdio
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl (program) 15

```
s/(.*)\.h/c\1/
```

It converts filenames supplied on std input, and needs to be run with the p flag, so that's one more character I believe. Eg

```
echo stdio.h | perl -p header.pl
```

output:

```
cstdio
```

Note to sticklers: I just spotted that this may be invalid because challenge implies that programs are only acceptable if the language *doesn't* support functions. However, I'm not going to throw it all away at this stage! Ah well.

Update: Augh! And I hadn't spotted page 2 of the answers either. Please refer to @malkaroee's effectively identical answer posted 4 months ago. ... Hang on, who resurrected this thread?

Answer (score 0):

### Lua, 39 bytes

```
function f(n)return "c"..n:sub(1,-3)end
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# 6, 52 bytes

```
class P{string C(string f)=>"c"+f.Replace(".h","");}
```

## C# <6, 58 bytes

```
class P{string C(string f){return"c"+f.Replace(".h","");}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 19

```
@(c)[99,c(1:end-2)]
```

Fairly straight forward. Prepends 'c' to the input string less the last two letters. MATLAB automatically converts the 99 (ASCII value) to 'c' when appending to a character string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 36 bytes

```
proc H h {set s c[regsub ..$ $h ""]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BDoMwDATvvMJCnHlAX8AfaA8mBJLKIZFtDhXi7eCU04xWq9Wqo@sqnB0MEOAQryDgRvar7BP0fQddgLb9nBclLLXSoIhn7UPj9Fe80TNv2bhQxppTTFGlSnZItZFQg8HWv6lUieuGVEVn5PWR2S@PxPyQ4vQXjlutaEy2dcJRdhW79XrDOBjt2w0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stackers](https://github.com/cheese3660/Stackers) (27 bytes)

```
«h ®h h cc ( ~ ~
```

### Ungolfed Version

```
«h "define a table called h
®h "read STDIN to h
h "read h to the stack
cc  "add the value for 'c' to the stack
(   "put c on the bottom of the stack
~ ~ "destroy the top two values on the stack
   "print stack bottom two top
```

Stackers is a programming language I created myself that is meant to be based on stacks, with variables and tables thrown in

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 41 bytes

```
	INPUT ARB . O RPOS(2)
	OUTPUT ='c' O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9PTLyA0RMExyElBT8FfISjAP1jDSJOL0z80BCRuq56sruDP5ern8v9/YnFxalGJXgYXAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `j`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
2ẓ'c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UpZS7IKlpSVpuhbLjB7umqyevKQ4KbkYKrRgeXFJSma-XgaECwA)

##### Explanation

```python
2ẓ'c  '# Implicit input
2ẓ     # Remove last two characters
  'c  '# Push the character "c"
       # Join the stack
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 13 bytes

```
{'c'~S/..$//}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCoAgFAWv8gipne5aVZfoAPERxUAzvm4k6uqmqxmGuQ37uYaC0WKtz6Snb1dSCqXemqhgEAfWDY@FON4BNjIWSslwlg46l9s0GuYrNlofqXd/hjOnLlGT70eg7KTb6g8)

`S/..$//` returns the result of chopping off the last two characters of the string, and `'c' ~` prepends a "c" to the front.