# Golf Practice: Pyth

Tags: code-golf, pyth

This is a challenge about the the tricks and optimizations that can be used when golfing in Pyth. Pyth golfers may recognize many of the tricks involved. However, unfamiliar approaches and constructs may  be involved, so take a look at the [Pyth Tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40039/tips-for-golfing-in-pyth) as well as the [Pyth Character Reference](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/) if you get stuck. Solutions may be tested [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/).

**Goal:** There are 8 problems, each with a Pyth snippet for you to optimize. Your goal is to create something equivalent but shorter. The reference solutions total 80 bytes. Your goal is to beat that by as much as possible.

The winner will go to the submission that solves all 8 problems with the  smallest total number of bytes. Tiebreaker is earlier post.

**Answering:** Please spoiler your entire answer, except for your total score. It is intended that you do not look at other people's answers before submitting your own.

Each submission should answer every problem and give the corresponding byte count, but feel free to use the reference implementation if you cannot improve it.

**Details:** If the question calls for a certain value or output, `q` equality is desired, so `1` and `!0` are equivalent. If the question calls for testing whether a condition is true, the output must be truthy if the condition is true and falsy if the condition is false, but is unconstrained beyond that. You may not swap true for false and false for true. If the question calls for something to be printed, nothing else may be printed except a trailing newline.

All answers must be valid for the most recent [Pyth commit](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) as of this question's posting.

**Problem 1:** Given a set in Q, output a list containing the elements of Q in any order.

```
; 3 bytes
f1Q
```

**Problem 2:** Output the list `[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]`.

```
; 9 bytes
[J1JZZJJZ
```

**Problem 3:** Given a positive integer in Q, test whether all of Q's digits are positive (not zero).

```
; 7 bytes
!f!TjQT
```

**Problem 4:** Given a string in z, test whether z contains any quotation marks - `"` or `'`.

```
; 9 bytes
|}\'z}\"z
```

**Problem 5:** Map Q=1 to 'Win', Q=0 to 'Tie' and Q=-1 to 'Lose'.

```
; 20 bytes
@["Tie""Win""Lose")Q
```

**Problem 6:** Print `0123456789`.

```
; 6 bytes
sm`dUT
```

**Problem 7:** Given a string in z, count the number of inversions.

(Indexes `i` and `j` form an inversion if `i < j` but `z[i] > z[j]`).

```
; 17 bytes
ssmm>@zd@zkrdlzUz
```

**Problem 8:** Given a list in z, count the number of repeated adjacent elements.

```
; 9 bytes
lfqFT.:z2
```

Comment: @user1737909 That answer is correct. `f1Q` filters `Q` on a function that is always true, so it always outputs every element of the set. `f` outputs a list, which meets the objective in that question.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because multi-part challenges with no interaction between the parts are disallowed. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8464/45941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post is for the accumulation of the best solutions across all answers. Please edit in the solution and the answerer who first found that solution if there any improvements.

## 48 bytes

> 1. `SQ` - 2 bytes, first posted by @orlp 
>  2. `jC\f2` - 5 bytes, first posted by @Maltysen 
>  3. `` -0`Q `` - 4 bytes, first posted by @Jakube 
>  4. `` @z`N `` - 4 bytes, mixture of @xnor and @Jakube, but not in any answers yet. 
>  (I didn't see it when writing the question, either) 
>  5. `@c3"LoseTieWin"hQ` - 17 bytes, first posted by @orlp 
>  6. `pMT` - 3 bytes, first posted by @Jakube 
>  7. `s>M.cz2` - 7 bytes, first posted by @orlp 
>  8. `sqVtzz` - 6 bytes, first posted by @Maltysen

Comment: are we restricting to Pyth versions from before the question ?

Comment: "All answers must be valid for the most recent Pyth commit as of this question's posting." Put I'd be interested to hear what you were thinking of. @Optimizer

Comment: Pyth is ever evolving, right ? (at a much faster pace than other golfing languages). So its very likely that this number (48) will easily go sub 40 in near future. And since this is a practice challenge, you would ideally want to practice using the latest Pyth version for newer challenges.

Answer (score 9):

## 52 bytes

> **Problem 1: 2 bytes**
>
> ```
>     SQ
> ```
>
> **Problem 2: 5 bytes**
>
> ```
>     jC\f2
> ```
>
> **Problem 3: 4 bytes**
>
> ```
>     -0`Q
> ```
>
> **Problem 4: 6 bytes**
>
> ```
>     @z+N\'
> ```
>
> **Problem 5: 17 bytes**
>
> ```
>     %3>"LTWoiisene"hQ
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>     @c3"LoseTieWin"hQ
> ```
>
> **Problem 6: 3 bytes**
>
> ```
>     pMT
> ```
>
> **Problem 7: 9 bytes**
>
> ```
>     s>R_d.cz2
> ```
>
> **Problem 8: 6 bytes**
>
> ```
>     sqVztz
> ```
>
> Combining @xnor's solution for problem 4 with mine (both 6 bytes) gives a nice [4 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40z%60N&debug=0) solution. So 48 bytes are possible.

Comment: You can't combine your solution with xnor's, because xnor's is invalid (see my comment on his answer).

Comment: @orlp *combining everything but the invalid stuff ;-) Added the solution in my post.

Comment: Ah, I see now :) Guess I was 6 bytes (and counting) worse than optimal.

Comment: aaah! thanks! hadn't realized :). I'll remove that.

Answer (score 7):

## 54 bytes

> **Task 1, 2 bytes**: `SQ`
>  **Task 2, 6 bytes**: `j102 2`
>  **Task 3, 5 bytes**: `*FjQT`
>  **Task 4, 6 bytes**: `@z"'\"`
>  **Task 5, 17 bytes**: `@c3"LoseTieWin"hQ`
>  **Task 6, 4 bytes**: `jkUT`
>  **Task 7, 7 bytes**: `s>M.cz2`
>  **Task 8, 7 bytes**: `sqM.:z2`

Comment: Nicely golfed :-)

Comment: is you answer for task 4 valid since on falsey it just prints a blank line?

Comment: @Maltysen Yes, because the truthy value of `""` is False because `not ""` is True.

Answer (score 3):

## 58 bytes

> **Task 1, 2 bytes**: `SQ`
>  **Task 2, 5 bytes**: `jC\f2`
>  **Task 3, 6 bytes**: `!}`Z`Q`
>  **Task 4, 8 bytes**: `|}\'z}Nz`
>  **Task 5, 18 bytes**: `@c"Tie\nWin\nLose"bQ`
>  **Task 6, 4 bytes**: `jkUT`
>  **Task 7, 9 bytes**: `lf>FT.cz2`
>  **Task 8, 6 bytes**: `sqVtzz`

Comment: I didn't know about `V` (although I still don't fully understand it, since you're doing vector operations on inequal length operands), so I'm excused for that one, but I really should've thought of `C\f` =/

Comment: @orlp `V` automatically truncates unequal inputs

Answer (score 2):

### 57 bytes

> 1. (2) `SQ` Sort.
>  2. (5) `jC\f2`  Convert `f` to ASCII val then base 2.
>  3. (5) `` /`Q`0 `` Count `'0'` in the number string.
>  4. (5) `` @z`\' `` Takes the set intersection of the string with `"'"`.
>  5. (18) `@c"Tie Win Lose"dQ` Makes the list with split. I didn't get slicing to work.
>  6. (4) `jkUT` Join `range(10)`. Apparently converts to a string automatically.
>  7. (9) `sm>d_d.:z`Counts substrings that are greater than their reverse.
>  8. (9) `l@C,zz.:z` Length of intersection of sublists of the list and pairs of elements in the list. Same length as reference solution.

Comment: Your solution for #4 is invalid. For example the string `te\\st` is a false positive.

Comment: @orlp Replaced it with different, shorter solution.