# Percent-Encode a String

Tags: code-golf, string

### Introduction

As some of you may know, URLs actually have a list of characters that do special things. For example, the `/` character separates parts of the URL, and the `?`, `&`, and `=` characters are used to pass query parameters to the server. In fact, there is a bunch of characters with special functions: `$&+,/:;=?@`. When you need to use these characters in the URL for any other reason besides the special functions, you have to do something called [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Percent encoding is when you take a character's hexadecimal value and prepend a `%` character to the beginning of it. For example, the character `?` would be encoded as `%3F`, and the character `&` would be encoded as `%26`. In a URL specifically, this allows you to send these characters as data via the URL without causing parsing problems. Your challenge will be to take a string, and percent-encode all of the characters that need to be encoded.

### The Challenge

You shall write a program or function that takes in a single string consisting of characters with codepoints 00-FF (ASCII and Extended ASCII characters). You will then have to output or return the same string with each character percent-encoded if necessary. **Built-ins that accomplish this task are not allowed, nor are standard loopholes.** For reference, here is a list of every character that needs to be percent encoded:

- Control characters (Codepoints 00-1F and 7F)
- Extended ASCII characters (Codepoints 80-FF)
- Reserved characters (`$&+,/:;=?@`, i.e. codepoints 24, 26, 2B, 2C, 2F, 3A, 3B, 3D, 3F, 40)
- Unsafe characters (`` " <>#%{}|\^~[]` ``, i.e. codepoints 20, 22, 3C, 3E, 23, 25, 7B, 7D, 7C, 5C, 5E, 7E, 5B, 5D, 60)

Here is a the same list, but instead as a list of decimal codepoints:

```
0-31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 43, 44, 47, 58, 59, 60, 62, 61, 63, 64, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128-255
```

**This is code golf, so shortest code in bytes (or approved alternative scoring method) wins!**

### Test Cases

```
http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/  =>  http%3A%2F%2Fcodegolf.stackexchange.com%2F
[@=>]{#}  =>  %5B%40%3D%3E%5D%7B%23%7D
Test String  =>  Test%20String
ÑÉÐÔ®  =>  %D1%C9%D0%D4%AE
  =>  %0F%16%7F (Control characters 0F, 16, and 7F)
 ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ  =>  %80%81%82%83%84%85%86%87%88%89%8A%8B%8C%8D%8E%8F%90%91%92%93%94%95%96%97%98%99%9A%9B%9C%9D%9E%9F%A0%A1%A2%A3%A4%A5%A6%A7%A8%A9%AA%AB%AC%AD%AE%AF%B0%B1%B2%B3%B4%B5%B6%B7%B8%B9%BA%BB%BC%BD%BE%BF%C0%C1%C2%C3%C4%C5%C6%C7%C8%C9%CA%CB%CC%CD%CE%CF%D0%D1%D2%D3%D4%D5%D6%D7%D8%D9%DA%DB%DC%DD%DE%DF%E0%E1%E2%E3%E4%E5%E6%E7%E8%E9%EA%EB%EC%ED%EE%EF%F0%F1%F2%F3%F4%F5%F6%F7%F8%F9%FA%FB%FC%FD%FE%FF (Extended ASCII characters 80-FF)
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~  =>  %20!%22%23%24%25%26'()*%2B%2C-.%2F0123456789%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5B%5C%5D%5E_%60abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%7B%7C%7D%7E
```

Comment: Would you have a testcase that shows the control characters?

Comment: @LeakyNun done.

Comment: I'm sure codepoint `EF` doesn't contain the question mark.

Comment: @zyabin101 where did you find that? Im not seeing it.

Comment: "For example, the character ? would be encoded as %EF..."

Comment: @zyabin101 Oops, thanks for catching that!

Comment: Could we have one string that tests basically the entire non-extended ASCII alphabet?

Comment: @orlp I added that string, as well as the entire printable ASCII range.

Comment: Is output case-sensitive? e.g., would `%2b` be acceptable instead of `%2B`?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem no. It is not case sensitive.

Comment: In the last test case, shouldn't the space get encoded as well?

Comment: @GamrCorps, will this pass test cases especially for `ÑÉÐÔ®` in python? -  `import re;f=lambda s:re.sub("[^-!'-*.\w]",lambda t:"%%%02X"%ord(t.group(0)),s)` I am not sure how does extended ascii supposed to work.

Comment: @Dennis indeed, thanks for noticing that.

Comment: Will there also be newlines in the input?

Comment: @Adnan Considering newlines are part of the 00-1F range, yes, newlines may be found in the input. Also, it does not matter if they are handled as `\r\n` or just `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, <strike>30 28</strike> 26 bytes

```
L?hx+G+rG1CGbb+\%.HCbsmydz
```

[try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3Fhx%2BG%2BrG1CGbb%2B%5C%25.HCbsmydz&input=http%3A%2F%2Fcodegolf.stackexchange.com%2F&debug=0)

### Explanation

```
L?hx+G+rG1CGbb+\%.HCbsmydz
L?hx+G+rG1CGbb+\%.HCb       First part, L defines the function y(b)
 ?hx+G+rG1CGbb+\%.HCb       ? is the ternary operator
  hx+G+rG1CGb               This part will be evaluated
  hx                        x will find the first occurence of a
                            character in a list. If it doesn't
                            find one, it will return -1. hx then
                            equals 0 (or false).
    +G+rG1CG                The list of allowed characters, a
                            concetanation (+) of the alphabet (G),
                            uppercase alphabet (rG1) and numbers
                            (CG, see below for details)
            b               The character to find in the list
             b              True branch of the ternary operator,
                            the character is allowed and returned.
              +\%.HCb       False branch, convert to hex and add %
                     smydz  The actual program
                      mydz  Map every character in the input (z)
                            using the function y on every d
                     s      Join the array, and implicit print.
```

`CG` is [this trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40039/tips-for-golfing-in-pyth/53383#53383) that generate a huge number that contains all possible digits. This is perfect, since we don't care for duplicates when checking whether a string is in another.

Comment: This answer does not meet the spec in the question. There are more allowed characters than just `A-Za-z0-9`. For example, `.` should be preserved rather than translated to `%2E`. (cc: @GamrCorps)

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 67 bytes/keystrokes

```
:s/\c[^a-z!'()*0-9._-]/\='%'.printf("%02x",char2nr(submatch(0)))/g<cr>
```

Note that `<cr>` represents the enter key, e.g. `0x0D` which is a single byte.

This is a pretty straightforward solution. Explanation:

```
:s/                                                                    "Search and replace
   \c                                                                  "Case-insensitive
     [^a-z!'()*0-9._-]/                                                "A negative range. Matches any character not alphabetc, numeric or in "!'()*0-9._-"
                       \=                                              "Evaluate
                         '%'                                           "a percent sign string
                            .                                          "Concatenated with
                             printf("%02x",char2nr(submatch(0)))       "The hex value of the character we just matched
                                                                /g     "Make this apply to ever match
                                                                  <cr> "Actually run the command
```

That `printf("%02x",char2nr(submatch(0)))` garbage is terribly *ungolfy*.

Comment: "That `printf("%02x",char2nr(submatch(0)))` garbage is terribly ungolfy" and extremely hacky

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 40 bytes

**39 bytes code + `-p`.**

A bit lame, but I think it's the shortest solution...

```pl
s/[^!'()*-.\w]/sprintf'%%%02x',ord$&/ge
```

#### Usage

```sh
echo -n ' !"#$%&'\''()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz{|}~' | perl -pe "s/[^'()*-.\w]/sprintf'%%%02x',ord$&/ge"
%20%21%22%23%24%25%26'()*+,-.%2f0123456789%3a%3b%3c%3d%3e%3f%40ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%5b%5c%5d%5e_%60abcdefghijklmnopqstuvwxyz%7b%7c%7d%7e
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 47 bytes

```julia
!s=replace(s,r"[^\w!'()*.-]",c->"%"hex(c[1],2))
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IXM9cmVwbGFjZShzLHIiW15cdyEnKCkqLi1dIixjLT4iJSJoZXgoY1sxXSwyKSkKCnByaW50KCdcdTAwMDAnOidcdTAwZmYnIHw-IGpvaW4gfD4gISk&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 92 bytes

**5 bytes thanks to orlp.**

**1 byte thanks to Sp3000.**

```python
import re;lambda s:''.join(re.match("[!'-*.0-9\w-]",c,256)and c or'%%%02X'%ord(c)for c in s)
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/N53v0B)

Comment: `re.match("[!'()*.0-9A-Za-z_-]",c)and c or'%%%02X'%ord(c)`

Comment: @Sp3000 ``\w`` includes extended ASCII

Comment: Also, `'()*` -> `'-*`

Comment: I think `\w` works with the `256` (`re.ASCII`) option: [ideone](http://ideone.com/LAPJ3v). It definitely works in Python 3 on ideone, and it *should* work with `u"..."` strings in Python 2, but ideone seems to do funky things to the latter (e.g. `print len(u"ÑÉÐÔ®")` gives 10 on [ideone](http://ideone.com/R1cDdL) but 5 on [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python) and my computer, despite all being 2.7.10)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 83 bytes

```c
f(char*p){for(;*p;++p)printf(isalnum(*p)||strchr("!'()*-._",*p)?"%c":"%%%02X",*p);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 86 bytes

```python
lambda s:"".join(["%%%02X"%ord(c),c][c<"{"and c.isalnum()or c in"!'()*-._"]for c in s)
```

Port of my C answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>28</s> 27 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḟØWḟ©“!'()*-.”Od⁴‘ịØH”%p®,y
```

This is a monadic link. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bifw5hX4bifwqnigJwhJygpKi0u4oCdT2TigbTigJjhu4vDmEjigJ0lcMKuLHkKMjU24bi24buMw4c&input=)

#### How it works

```
ḟØWḟ©“!'()*-.”Od⁴‘ịØH”%p®,y  Monadic link. Argument: s (string)

 ØW                          Yield “0...9A...Z_a...z”.
ḟ                            Remove these characters from s.
     “!'()*-.”               Yield “!'()*-.”.
   ḟ                         Remove these characters from s.
    ©                        Copy the result to the register.
              O              Ordinal; get the code point of each character.
               d⁴            Divmod 16; yield quotient and remainder modulo 16.
                 ’           Decrement the results.
                  ịØH        Index into “0123456789ABCDEF”.
                     ”p%     Perform Cartesian product with ”%, prepending it to
                             each pair of hexadecimal digits.
                        ®,   Yield [t, r], where t is the string in the register
                             and r the result of the Cartesian product.
                          y  Use this pair to perform transliteration on s.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 37 + 3 = 40 bytes

Run with `-p` (3 extra bytes), like `$ ruby -p percent_encode.rb`:

```rb
gsub(/[^\w!'()*-.]/){"%%%02X"%$&.ord}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <del>201</del> <del>179</del> <del>178</del> <del>127</del> 119 bytes

```haskell
import Data.Char;import Numeric;f=(=<<)(\c->if isAlphaNum c&&isAscii c||elem c"-_.~"then[c]else '%':(showHex$ord c)"")
```

Ungolfed:

```haskell
import Data.Char
import Numeric

f=(=<<) e
e c = if isAlphaNum c && isAscii c && c `elem` "-_.~" then [c] else '%' : (showHex $ ord c) ""
```

Comment: Can you remove a bunch of the spaces?

Comment: You can loose the `where`, turn the `if` into guards, make e partial, loose the last argument of `showHex`, inline `p`, inline `s`, loose the signature, reorder the `elem` and loose even more whitespace. As a first approximation I got down to 118 that way.

Comment: Thanks @MarLinn for a bunch of good suggestions on trimming down the code. However, I had some trouble with certain suggestions. First of all, if I remove the signature, GHC will complain that `No instance for (Foldable t0) arising from a use of ‘foldr’`. It says that the type of the function is ambiguous, resulting in an inferred binding of `f :: t0 Char -> [Char]`. And second of all, I could not remove the empty string argument from showHex as it returns a ShowS, which is a type alias for `String -> String` thus needing the empty string.

Comment: @sham1, yes, `ShowS` takes a String... but you have one: the one you're adding with `(++)`. So you can loose both at the same time. That's actually why `ShowS` looks that way. I don't get the type error, so I guess it's a version thing? Two other things I noticed by now: `otherwise` can always be replaced by `1<2` (a shorthand for `True`), but if you return to `if` instead you can inline `e` and drop all names. And even turn the fold into a `concatMap`, i.e. a `(>>=)`. Doesn't save a lot, but at least a little. Might solve the type error, too.

Answer (score 1):

### 16/32-bit x86 assembly, 73 bytes

Byte code:

```
AC 3C 21 72 2A 74 3E 3C 26 76 24 3C 2B 72 36 3C
2C 76 1C 3C 2F 72 2E 74 16 3C 3A 72 28 74 10 3C
5F 74 22 50 0C 60 3C 60 74 02 3C 7B 58 72 16 D4
10 3C 09 1C 69 2F 86 E0 3C 09 1C 69 2F 92 B0 25
AA 92 AA 86 E0 AA E2 B8 C3
```

Disassembly:

```
l0: lodsb         ;fetch a character
    cmp  al, 21h
    jb   l1       ;encode 0x00-0x20
    je   l2       ;store 0x21
    cmp  al, 26h
    jbe  l1       ;encode 0x22-0x26
    cmp  al, 2bh
    jb   l2       ;store 0x27-0x2A
    cmp  al, 2ch
    jbe  l1       ;encode 0x2B-0x2C
    cmp  al, 2fh
    jb   l2       ;store 0x2D-0x2E
    je   l1       ;encode 0x2F
    cmp  al, 3ah
    jb   l2       ;store 0x30-0x39
    je   l1       ;encode 0x3A
    cmp  al, 5fh
    je   l2       ;store 0x5F
    push eax
    or   al, 60h  ;merge ranges
    cmp  al, 60h
    je   l3       ;encode 0x40, 0x60
    cmp  al, 7bh
l3: pop  eax
    jb   l2       ;store 0x41-0x5A, 0x61-0x7A
                  ;encode 0x3B-0x3F, 0x5B-0x5E, 0x7B-0xFF

l1: aam  10h      ;split byte to nibbles
    cmp  al, 9    ;convert 0x0A-0x0F 
    sbb  al, 69h  ;to
    das           ;0x41-0x46 ('A'-'F')
    xchg ah, al   ;swap nibbles
    cmp  al, 9    ;do
    sbb  al, 69h  ;other
    das           ;half
    xchg edx, eax ;save in edx
    mov  al, '%'
    stosb         ;emit '%'
    xchg edx, eax
    stosb         ;emit high nibble
    xchg ah, al

l2: stosb         ;emit low nibble or original character
    loop l0       ;until end of string
    ret
```

Call with:
- esi = pointer to buffer that holds source string;
- edi = pointer to buffer that receives encoded string;
- ecx = length of source string.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 78 bytes

```
lambda s:"".join(["%%%02x"%ord(c),c][c.isalnum()or c in"!'()*-._"]for c in s)
```

More nicely formatted:

```
lambda s:
    "".join(["%%%02x" % ord(c), c][c.isalnum() or c in"!'()*-._"] for c in s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SQF](https://community.bistudio.com/wiki/SQF_syntax), <s>199</s> 176

Using the function-as-a-file format:

```
i="";a="0123456789ABCDEF!'()*-.GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_";{i=i+if((toUpper _x)in a)then{_x}else{x=(toArray[_x])select 0;"%"+(a select floor(x/16))+(a select(x%16))}}forEach _this;i
```

Call as `"STRING" call NAME_OF_COMPILED_FUNCTION`

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 146 bytes

```
param($n)37,38+0..36+43,44,47+58..64+91,93+96+123..255-ne33|%{$n=$n-replace"[$([char]$_)]",("%{0:x2}"-f$_)};$n-replace'\\','%5c'-replace'\^','%5e'
```

Long because I wanted to show a different approach rather than just copy-pasting the same regex string that every else is using.

Instead here, we loop through every code point that *must* be percent-encoded, and do a literal `-replace` on the input string `$n` each iteration (re-saving back into `$n`). Then we need to account for the two special characters that need escaping, `\` and `^`, so those are in separate `-replace` elements at the end. Since we didn't re-save that final string, it's left on the pipeline and printing is implicit.