# Fetch the answer from the Internet

Tags: code-golf, internet

So, normally, this is a [forbidden loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062/98630) to fetch the desired output from an external source. But this challenge is an exception ! In this challenge you will **have** to fetch data from the internet and output it to the SDTOUT.

## The task

1. For the purpose of this challenge, you'll be the owner of the imaginary `a.pi` domain!
2. You will need to take the first argument from STDIN, pass it to `a.pi/{arg}`, and print the result to STDOUT.
3. You don't need to handle errors, the server is always up and running !
4. This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the winner is the shortest (in bytes or [equivalent](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=program%20size)) valid answer.

## Rules

1. You are allowed to invoke [`curl`](https://curl.se/) and [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) <sup>**[1]**</sup> commands as child/sub-processes (like `child_process` with NodeJS).
2. The ressource at `a.pi` will only be available in the `http` and `https` protocol in their default ports (`80` and `443` respectively), you don't need to include the `http://` if your language allow to ommit it.
3. Only the desired output (http response) should be printed, nothing else (no `GET http://a.pi/:` or whatever).
4. <strike>The input might contain spaces or otherwise [reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters), and need to be **percent-encoded**.</strike>
   Spaces ( ) should be replaced with `%20` and `%` with `%25` (As [spaces **cannot** be in URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space)). The other characters (including reserved ones) don't need to be encoded, but you **can** encode them (including [unreserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#:%7E:text=RFC%203986%20section%202.3) characters) if that makes your code shorter.
5. If your language/environement doesn't have a STDIN/STDOUT (like in a browser), the shortest equivalent can be used (like `prompt()` and `alert()` in javascript).
6. The [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) Headers are open for any external requests (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`), if you where wondering.

> **Note:** to test your program, you can use any domain and then replace it with `a.pi` for the submission.

<sup>**[1]**</sup> While it should works the same everywhere, I'd recommend you to precise which OS you used for testing.

## Updates

Rule 4 have been modified as it was the hardest part is the percent-encoding, which is already a [submitted code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89767/percent-encode-a-string), and the exact rules of the encoding where unclear.

> **Note:** this the first code-golf challenge that I submit, and I didn't knew about the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) before. In the future, I'll definitely post here before submitting.
> Also, this change doesn't affect previous entries (Except for their length).

Comment: Points 1 and 2 are unclear and basically unobservable. `curl` and `wgets` are essentially language-specific tools, and what do you mean by "*the* included library"? I suggest you use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/66833) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thanks for pointing this out! I removed the rule 1 (and shifted the rule numbers) So now you are allowed to use these command-line tools no matter what, as choosing which methot is shorter (like child_process vs http.get()) is part of the challenge. Btw I didn't knew about the Sandbox, I'll use it for next golf challenges that comes to my mind.

Comment: Are spaces the only characters we should percent-encode (`%20`)? If not, what are all possible inputs (Letters/digits/spaces only? Printable ASCII only?), and which need to be encoded besides spaces? Also, are `+` allowed to encode spaces specifically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Percent-Encode a String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89767/percent-encode-a-string)

Comment: This looks like the main task here is percent-encoding the input string (for which we have a challenge: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89767/percent-encode-a-string).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I made rule 4 simplier (previous entries are still valid)
Also, I'll definitely use the sandbox from now on

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>29</s> 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„ %DÇh'%ì‡"a.pi/"ì.w
```

-9 bytes now that the encoding rule (4) has changed.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Dc/pUpJhGAbgUyGKbNX2xfayfS/bF8OipEUpMNvn5RMBLVuAChUJUHEjZd/Bmefmo5mceYdO4TkR4t/19@ox6zuNhnqdhV@ja4Ojq0mHCIugVt9sMrZoEWnuq9fbDWaLxtht6rW0alZoV67SrW5as3bd@g0bm1s2bd6yddv2HTt37W7ds3ff/gMHDx0@0nb02PETJ0@dPnP23PkLFy9dbr9y9dr1Gzdv3b5zt@OevvP@A8PDR13Gx0@ePuvuMT1/Ybb0vux79frN23fvP/wZ/@uSMRmXCZmUKZmWGZmtxWvZWrFW@qdIt/RIr8zJCTnLgwF2DrFzmJ1@VqysKKz0s2JjZYAVezXFSkSOsRituho1FmEWgUZr2c4iqjaUU10Vu1qqpiuChZfFCAsfi3EWIRZuFp5lH9tCapBFXnVXHGpZzVasFKQQTdAkTVGYpmmGZmmO5ikiC7RAixSlGMUpQUlKUZoylKUc5alARSpRmZYgYIWCftgwADsccGIQQ/iITxjGZ3zBV3yDC2548B0/8BNejGAUY/BhHH78QgBBhDCBSUwhjGnMYBZzmEcEv7GARUQRQxwJJJFCGhlkkUMeBRRRQhlL/wE) (where `.w` will act as no-op, since it's disabled on TIO).

**Original 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer encoding all reserved and non-ASCII characters:**

```
žj“"+-.<>“«мDÇh'%ì‡"a.pi/"ì.w
```

\$\frac{2}{3}rd\$ of the program is used to encode the characters (19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) to be exact).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DdDpUpJhGIfxUzHKrExsX8xss30v21csS6yUQrN9Hl4R0LIFqFzAWBRFSFlkX5y5/7w0kzPP0CncJ0J8@329rj6jrlPfVa2qxR4WLk1jk7a1rQYKVfLtsHY31CPMwqvRaQ36Zg3C2sFqtaPL2F@n7zUM9LfUrdGsXVe/vmHDxk2Nm5u0zVu2btu@Y@eu3Xv2tuxr3d924OChw0fajx47fuLkqdNnzp47f@HipcsdV65eu37j5q3bd@7eu6/rfPCw69Hjbn3Pk6fPevsMz18Y@wdeDr56/ebtu/cf/rj/2mVUxmRcLsuETMqUTFdilXQlXyn8U6RDOuW4zEi/DPKIh22jbBtj2zQrJlYUVoZYMbMyzIqlnGAlLKdYTJbtLKZZBFh4almrFhYRtaaMai9Z1EI5WRIsxllM1BawcLPwsXCwcK662OxTvSyyqqNkVYtqumQiL/nITzM0SwGao3kK0gKFKCxztEhLFKEoxShOy5SgJKUoTRnKUo7yVKAirUDABAVDMGMYFlhhwwhG8RGfMIbP@IKv@AY7HHDiO37gJ8YxgUlMwQU3pvELHnjhgx8zmEUAc5hHEAsIIYzfWMQSIogihjiWkUASKaSRQRY55FFAESv/AQ) (where `.w` will act as no-op, since it's disabled on TIO).

**Explanation:**

```python
„ %                # Push string " %"
   D               # Duplicate this string
    Ç              # Convert it to a list of codepoint integers
     h             # Convert each integer to hexadecimal
      '%ì         '# Prepend a "%" in front of each
         ‡         # Transliterate all characters in the (implicit) input-string
          "a.pi/"ì # Prepend "a.pi/" in front of it
.w                 # Browse this page (with leading "http://" implicitly added) and
                   # read and push its contents
                   # (after which this is output implicitly as result)

žj                 # Push builtin "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_"
  “"+-.<>“«       "# Append string '"+-.<>'
           м       # Remove all these characters from the (implicit) input-string,
                   # so we're left with all reserved and/or non-ASCII characters
DÇh'%ì‡"a.pi/"ì.w '# Same as above
```

Comment: I half expected the "bytes" link in "19 bytes" to link to [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240) :P

Comment: Shouldn't that be "⅔ʳᵈˢ"?

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```js
x=>fetch('/'+escape(x))
```

Percent encode builtin FTW!!!

Returns a `Promise` containing an object with a `text` method, which when called with no properties returns the result, allowed by [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/100664https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12327/100664).

Must be run on the `a.pi` domain, allowed by [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13621/can-js-answers-require-the-code-to-be-run-at-a-certain-domain). Since this is impossible, try running the following in your console, on this site:

```js
f=
x=>fetch('/'+escape(x))

f('questions').then(x=>x.text()).then(console.log)
```

(This requests the questions page)

Comment: Can you use `escape` instead of `encodeURI`?

Comment: @DomHastings Yep!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -nlMv5.10, 50 bytes

```perl
s/\W/sprintf"%%%02x",ord$&/ge;say`curl -s a.pi/$_`
```

[Can't try it online](https://tio.run/##HcqxDsIgEADQX7lgcZJSTTr5DZ0cXEyEKLaXECDcWfTnPY3zeyXUOMoGTs0X4CUAtwwOGvICCjjDiqH94VmjkL2cLZWKiR9Kaz0cXmqX673b2jkcyb/d7dfAEPi@oO2uTsTXGTgQf3JhzInEpChmWsd@P3wB) unless you swap the two `` ` `` chars with `"` to output the curl command with it's arguments instead of it's response. Percent-encodes all chars except `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>54</del> 47 bytes

```php
<?=join(file('http://a.pi/'.urlencode($argn)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Kz8zTyMtMydVQz2jpKTASl8/Ua8gU19dr7QoJzUvOT8lVUMlsSg9T1NT0/r//7T8/H/5BSWZ@XnF/3XdAA)

Note: TIO does not allow external requests, though it probably doesn't really matter since `a.pi` does not really exist.

-7 bytes thx to @Kaddath!

Comment: You should be able to replace `file_get_contents()` by `join(file())` and save 7 bytes ;)

Comment: @Kaddath nice one! Thx buddy!

Comment: Using [`readfile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) would make it even shorter by a pair of parenthesis and the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 77 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```cs
a=>new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("a.pi/"+Uri.EscapeDataString(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcuxCsIwEIDh3ac4MiWoEXWs7dLqJC5FOp/xKgfxUpJI8ekjqNM/fPwurV3icnqJO6QcWR4r@LWBEWooWDdCM/TvlOlpL5TtQLfWM0nWxnZhFh/w3n8XrdBOvFHLa2R7TA4n6jDjH9GYUi3aICl4skPkTGcW0qNWW9jBXhlTlQ8)

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 34 bytes

If you only need to return the URL + encoded query string like in some of the answers.

```cs
a=>"a.pi/"+Uri.EscapeDataString(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrqMAoe0U0hRsFf4n2topJeoVZOoraYcWZeq5FicnFqS6JJYkBoNVaSRq/rfmcs7PK87PSdULL8osSfXJzEvVSNNQMlQwUjBW0tS0/g8A)

Comment: You can remove the `{return ;}`: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcuxCsIwEIDh3ac4MiWoEXWs7dLqJC5FOp/xKgfxUpJI8ekjqNM/fPwurV3icnqJO6QcWR4r@LWBEWooWDdCM/TvlOlpL5TtQLfWM0nWxnZhFh/w3n8XrdBOvFHLa2R7TA4n6jDjH9GYUi3aICl4skPkTGcW0qNWW9jBXhlTlQ8)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `http.client`, 42 bytes

```
[ url-encode "a.pi/"prepend http-get nip ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcwxDsIwDEbhvaf4lb1BwAYHQCwsiAkxRKkpFpFjHPf8Abo@fXrPlL1av13Pl9MBjT4LSaaGl7vGXJjEsVhp8ZfrxDLjTSZUwBXHYQhb7LAP/f5H42oIIUXlTVAjJZnW1TiTQ1jx6DmVAjUW718)

Answer (score 0):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 122 bytes

```gawk
BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n";s="/inet/tcp/0/a.pi/80"}1gsub("%","%25")gsub(FS,"%20"){print"GET /"$0|&s;while((s|&getline)>0)print$0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNjWH4iVYopi8pSsi22V9DPzUkv0S5IL9A30E/UKMvUtDJRqDdOLS5M0lFSVdJRUjUyVNMFct2AQz0BJs7qgKDOvRMndNURBX0nFoEat2Lo8IzMnVUOjuEYtPbUkB2ikpp2BJliZikHt//8A)

> [NO WAY! I didn't know AWK could do that!](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawkinet/gawkinet.html)

```
BEGIN{RS=ORS="\r\n";
```

We start by setting `\r\n`(`CR LF`) as the trailing character of the print function, as the default is only `\n`.

```
s="/inet/tcp/0/a.pi/80"}
```

And then we set the server we want to communicate with.

```
1gsub("%","%25")gsub(FS,"%20")
```

This AWK pattern will always return true, even if there are no spaces or `%` in the input.

```
{print"GET /"$0|&s;while((s|&getline)>0)print$0}
```

The last piece of code `GET`s the domain response until the last line.

For this code to work, make sure to input the wanted `ARG` as in `a.pi/{ARG}`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or your most favorite ASCII-4-End-of-transmission way of doing it).

Comment: Point 3. says “You don't need to handle errors”, so you can skip comparing `getline` against 0. Also `print` without argument will print `$0`, so no need to specify it.