# Could They Be The Same Day Of The Week?

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, decision-problem, date

#### Challenge

Given a non-negative integer, output whether it is possible for two dates (of the Gregorian calendar) differing by exactly that many years to share a day of the week. A year is assumed to be a leap year either if it is divisible by 4 but not by 100, or if it is divisible by 400.

Output may be:

- [falsey/truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/53748) (in either orientation)
- any two distinct values
- one distinct value and one being anything else
- by program return code
- by success/error
- by any other reasonable means - just ask if you suspect it may be controversial

But **not** by two non-distinct sets of values, except for falsey/truthy (as this would allow a no-op!)

#### Detail

This is whether the input is a member of [OEIS sequence A230995](http://oeis.org/A230995).

Members:

```
0, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 17, 18, 22, 23, 28, 29, 33, 34, 35, 39, 40, 45, 46, 50, 51, 56, 57, 61, 62, 63, 67, 68, 73, 74, 78, 79, 84, 85, 89, 90, 91, 95, 96, 101, 102, 106, 107, 108, 112, 113, 114, 117, 118, 119, 123, 124, 125, 129, 130, 131, 134, 135, 136, 140, 141, 142, 145, 146, 147, 151, 152, 153, 157, 158, 159, 162, 163, 164, 168, 169, 170, 173, 174, 175, 179, 180, 181, 185, 186, 187, 190, 191, 192, 196, 197, 198, 202, 203, 204, 208, 209, 210, 213, 214, 215, 219, 220, 221, 225, 226, 227, 230, 231, 232, 236, 237, 238, 241, 242, 243, 247, 248, 249, 253, 254, 255, 258, 259, 260, 264, 265, 266, 269, 270, 271, 275, 276, 277, 281, 282, 283, 286, 287, 288, 292, 293, 294, 298, 299, 304, 305, 309, 310, 311, 315, 316, 321, 322, 326, 327, 332, 333, 337, 338, 339, 343, 344, 349, 350, 354, 355, 360, 361, 365, 366, 367, 371, 372, 377, 378, 382, 383, 388, 389, 393, 394, 395
plus
400, 405, 406, 407, 411, ...
```

Non-members:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 30, 31, 32, 36, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 44, 47, 48, 49, 52, 53, 54, 55, 58, 59, 60, 64, 65, 66, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75, 76, 77, 80, 81, 82, 83, 86, 87, 88, 92, 93, 94, 97, 98, 99, 100, 103, 104, 105, 109, 110, 111, 115, 116, 120, 121, 122, 126, 127, 128, 132, 133, 137, 138, 139, 143, 144, 148, 149, 150, 154, 155, 156, 160, 161, 165, 166, 167, 171, 172, 176, 177, 178, 182, 183, 184, 188, 189, 193, 194, 195, 199, 200, 201, 205, 206, 207, 211, 212, 216, 217, 218, 222, 223, 224, 228, 229, 233, 234, 235, 239, 240, 244, 245, 246, 250, 251, 252, 256, 257, 261, 262, 263, 267, 268, 272, 273, 274, 278, 279, 280, 284, 285, 289, 290, 291, 295, 296, 297, 300, 301, 302, 303, 306, 307, 308, 312, 313, 314, 317, 318, 319, 320, 323, 324, 325, 328, 329, 330, 331, 334, 335, 336, 340, 341, 342, 345, 346, 347, 348, 351, 352, 353, 356, 357, 358, 359, 362, 363, 364, 368, 369, 370, 373, 374, 375, 376, 379, 380, 381, 384, 385, 386, 387, 390, 391, 392, 396, 397, 398, 399
plus
401, 402, 403, 404, 408, ...
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in each language wins!

Comment: Can output be: program ends (within less than 30 seconds) if input belongs to the sequence, or runs indefinitely (infinite loop) otherwise?

Comment: @LuisMendo I'll allow a program that does that so long as it is accompanied with a program that provides the time limit (so one may acquire it prior for one's hardware). It is indeed controversial though :)

Comment: In which situation is a number divisible by 400 but is not divisible by 100?

Comment: @ATaco In none. The exception to the *every fourth year* rule are years that are divisible by 4 and 100, but not by 400.

Comment: @ATaco maybe the wording is clearer now

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks. Can you elaborate what you mean by “a program that provides the time limit”? You probably don’t mean just to print a number of seconds, or is that it?

Comment: @LuisMendo I do mean that - a guaranteed upper bound (otherwise I must accept a program whose author says "within 3 days" or whatever :p) TIO times things so maybe just wrap your program to run the most expensive input twice?

Comment: @JonathanAllan 30 seconds suffice in TIO. I've explained that in my answer; please let me know if it's enough and clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
`0Gv@+5:YcYO8XOda
```

The program halts if the input belongs to the sequence, or runs indefinitely (infinite loop) otherwise.

Let `n` be the input. The code executes a loop that tests years `1` and `1+n`; then `2` and `2+n`; ... until a matching day of the week is found. If no matching exists the loop runs indefinitely.

The membership function for `n` is periodic with period `400`. Therefore, at most `400` iterations are needed if `n` belongs to the sequence. This requires less than 20 seconds in Try It Online. As a proof of this upper bound, here's a [modified program](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HAvcxB29QqMjnS3yLCPyXRwcTA0Ebr/38TAxMA) that limits the number of iterations to 400 (by adding `@401<*` at the end). Note also that this bound is loose, and a few seconds usually suffice.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HAvcxB29QqMjnS3yLCPyXx/38TA1MA)

#### Explanation

```
`           % Do...while
  0Gv       %   Push column vector [0; n], where n is the input number
  @+        %   Add k, element-wise. Gives [k; k+n]
  5:        %   Push row vector [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  Yc        %   Horizontal "string" concatenation: gives the 2×6 matrix
            %   [k, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; k+n, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. The 6 columns
            %   represent year, month, day, hour, minute, second
  YO        %   Convert each row to serial date number. Gives a column
            %   vector of length 2
  8XO       %   Convert each date number to date string with format 8,
            %   which is weekday in three letters ('Mon', 'Tue', etc).
            %   This gives a 2×3 char matrix such as ['Wed';'Fri']
  d         %   Difference (of codepoints) along each column. Gives a
            %   row vector of length 3
  a         %   True if some element is nonzero, or false otherwise
            % End (implicit). The loop proceeds with the next iteration
            % if the top of the stack is true
```

---

### Old version, 24 bytes

```
400:"0G&v@+5:YcYO8XOdavA
```

Output is `0` if the input belongs to the sequence, or `1` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/38TAwErJwF2tzEHb1CoyOdLfIsI/JbHMESRjCgA)

#### Explanation

```
400         % Push row vector [1, 2, ..., 400]
"           % For each k in that array
  0G&v      %   Push column vector [0; n], where n is the input number
  @+        %   Add k, element-wise. Gives [k; k+n]
  5:        %   Push row vector [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  Yc        %   Horizontal "string" concatenation: gives the 2×6 matrix
            %   [k, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; k+n, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. The 6 columns
            %   represent year, month, day, hour, minute, second
  YO        %   Convert each row to serial date number. Gives a column
            %   vector of length 2
  8XO       %   Convert each date number to date string with format 8,
            %   which is weekday in three letters ('Mon', 'Tue', etc).
            %   This gives a 2×3 char matrix such as ['Wed';'Fri']
  d         %   Difference (of codepoints) along each column. Gives a
            %   row vector of length 3
  a         %   True if some element is nonzero, or false otherwise
  v         %   Concatenate vertically with previous results
  A         %   True if all results so far are true
            % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Comment: Seems good, my request was really that I'd like to know the worst case input, or have a program which forces the 400 iterations -- that way one could get an upper bound wherever one chooses to run it. (BTW I think the infinite loop is, in practice, ended by an out of bounds error.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks. I see. I've added a modified program that limits the number of iterations to 400. It takes about 14 seconds, so I'm using 20 seconds as upper bound

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
u=-abs(200-input()%400)-4
print u/100+5>(u-8)*5/4%7>u%4/-3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZhNrybHbUb39SsuFAiYcUZQdX2SCcZA9l55a2ShyKNYMHwljGaA5Ncr5/BmkVUWfPF2F7u6i4fdxYe//veXv/3yOn7/9F@ffvzmm29@//rxux/@47d3o/fvfn799euXd@@/Xb2//261Xz///Prl5ev3T@//vP/47ut38f4P@/v17f3j12/X99/N37n8Dw8XtvZPL//29csv//jhy6e/vvz4t08//r21v3766eWnd6/v/@X/3OD1f6f@18@fvnz9/Pr/zN3anz7@pX942R9ezoeX@@HlebCB@T8@vAz@j4n5Pz@8TP7PhXHF5Hhx8eL/4vLtRFy//c/1h/@H6w/XHI@Z4/L/cv31P9cH/4Prg//J9ck1yXEyx9N9mO7T9Dr0mXr4kJ57pj/Ln3rwGkgf34HhwNj@eG52f5zPp398/Gc6qQt4lgPLSV3Ls2rASV3Osx3YTrrrnDfaTuriHlf3HCd1fc9x4DqpS31c63Od1NU@4UA4qYt@whuFk7r2x8U/6aS1/KwBA28MRhdDX/7UOeYbT/fHAQMxnu2PA8OB8fjjuXH8ubJ0wECMWWgdmDXgpAZiGIixnNQYjFUDTmoMxvZG20kNxDAQ4zipMRjHgeOkBmIYiHGd1BiM68B1UmMwwhtFZZcDUQOVaA6kA@mkFYM0@1z@7Oaey58uf5qy05XPh1mmi56m7Rx1eE1aDyt1Zx2GP06wKp2d1AVOM3juSm/nc1nTLJ6nDp3PRJ6uaF4nvXXofC5mupgZdeh8LmG6hGlO81L6U/@OP1y7fPplPq@nDrl2@fTLLF6jDn3PfPpl7i5zd9W7Vy9fvX1m7Nr1LjrfrkPn8@mXebrM03XqnJOancvsXLcOnc@XcZmYy6df5uQyJ1c9fdYr7vttOu5eh9ef8L33nJm4zcTtYvZTA0y1Xcz2ldym43ZF20zcZuJ2WdtlbdNxu6xtJm4zcbvAXd8X03HXF8ZXcpuOe9c5b2Qmbpe6Xeo2HbdL3WbiNhO3i94uepuO20VvX8ltOm5Xvs3EbSZul79d/jYddy0/a4BJjzE4vpLHnDy9zqUfve6PAwbimJjHGBxfyTPqm@g5s/OYncdAHANxZn0tHZg14KQG4hiIY7IeY3BWDTipMThm7DFjj4E4BuKYu8cYHHP3mLvHQBwDcUzgYwyOr@S59XX2nFl8zOJjIE7UgJMag2M@H/P5VAx8Ja/Lvyb1dfnX5V@T@rry6yt5XfQ1qe@ow@s@4KFJfWcd1t7gBKt2CCd1gdekvi7wusDrsq5JfU8dOp9JfV3R9ZW8tw6dz8VcF3OjDp3PJVyXcE3q8JWMXv@OP1wbPn2Yz/HUIdeGTx9mcYw6dOvy6cPcDXM3Zm1nzmfGhhkbPn2YsbHr0Pl8@jBPwzyNU@ec1OwMszNuHTpf7Y@1Qfr0YU6GORn19OZk@kqm6Zi9Dq8/4VbqOTMxzcR0MfnUgJuti0lfyTQd0xWlmZhmYrqsdFlpOqbLSjMxzcR0gblqwEl3bdoOmI6565w3MhPTpaZLTdMxXWqaiWkmpotOF52mY7ro9JVM0zFdeZqJaSZmVQhVIpiOWcvPGnDr7W@lgi8lv6t@385nFRO9fmu0yoZuhvJbo6NGx1vFUedH1Ryjio4qH3rVD33WXap46PNttO5SRUSvKqKvukuVEH29jdZdqorou@6@6y5VTfQqJ/qpu1Qt0U@NnrpL1RS9iop@6y5VUfT7VhW9lUV1PuruUXep4qLH22jdpUqLnjWadZe3uPkeP09F7PFd4LfOVMSeKgmfitXj60z1VWdGFWHj7UxVYPOtLKu6bL6dqaJs1mzrrV6ru1Q0nl3zVzSeisZTEXhOzX/eztT8p2artT@37nLfztT8teqnVv3E25mav1b61Eqf3P/e2p9fPr785fXlp18@v7y@/Pz68vmH1//89M7a@v3Lz291NF4//Pbbp89fXv708eOff@/taaPNttpup90WLdvDyac9oz2zPas9uz2nPbc90Z5so7fBNaON2cZqY7dx2rhtRBvZZm/zaZMpZ5urzd3mafO2GW1mW72tp63RFndcbe22Tlu3rWgr2@5tP22PtmfbPNBu@7R92462s53eztPOaGe2s9rheU87t51oJ9vt7T7tjnZnu6vd3S7Lue1Gu9mit3hajBazxWqxW5wWrDZaZMve8mk5Ws6Wq@VueVrelgTDaBCOTjw6AelEpBOSTkw6QelEpROWjl@FDT8DZ@QMnbEzeEbP8BE/aGDGFz9iSCWP4UcYyTMMPyJJSY/hNwWBH@GkrsfwI6LkHoYfQaXAx/BbEsOPyFLlY/gRXPIRjPgRX8p9DL8tWvwIMoU/hh9xJkcx/Ag1xT@G3zEH8CPeyAAMP0JOxmL4EXWkAIbfNVnwI/SIArIGP6JPFmP4AQB1gOEXZhV@UEAiYPgBgszG8IMFWgHDL00/848EhAeiASMH4THgMeAx4IF6wPB7TFT84IGEwPCDx4DHgMeAxzCfTejKaPzMaZParDatzWsTGx4oCwy/aerjB48BDyQGhh88BjwGPNAZGH7LdwQ/eAx4IDgw/OAx4DHgMeCB8sB8mfCDx4AH8gPDDx4DHgMeAx7oEMy3Dj94DHggRngF8YPHgMeAx4AHqgTz9cQPHgMeAx7IEww/eAx4DHigUTDfY/zgMeAx4IFYwfCDx4DHgMeAB6oF843nlYfHhMeEBxoG472Hx4THhAdqhs@Cnwb84DHhMeGBrMHwg8eEx4THhAciB8MPHhMeEx7IHQw/eEy/NH5q/NbUxwY/Pzd@b/zg@MXxkwOPCY8JjwkP9BCGHzwmPCY8JjxQR3yq8IPHhMeEBzoJww8eEx4THhMeqCYMP3hMeEx4oJ8w/OAx4THhMeGBkMLwg8eEx4THvH4Q8YPHhMeEx4QHAgvDDx4THhMeM/xy4gePCY8JjwkPhBeGHzwmPCY8ZvqJ9RvLRxYeCx4LHgseiDKMTy08FjwWPNbjxxg/eCx4LHgseCx4oNUw/OCx4LGGX2384LHgseCx4LHggYbD8IPHgseaft7xgwdaDsMPHgseyz3ATcBdwG2g9gH83AncCtwL3AzggdzD8IPHgsfabhj4wQPth@EHjwUPZCCGHzwWPNZxZ8EPHshBDD94LHgseKAOMfzgsa5bEH7wQCayF@EHjwWPBQ9UI4YfPFa4V@EHD@Qjhh88FjwWPBCSGH7wWOmm5q7GtgYPVCXGzgaPDQ8EJsbuBo8Nj/24/eEHD4Qmhh88NjyQmxh@8Njw2MN9Ej94IDsx/OCx4bHhgQBlE8UPHnu6oeIHD0Qohh88Njw2PJCjGH7w2MudFz94IEkx/OCx3Z3dnt2f3aDdoWuLxs9N2l3abRoeGx4bHkhVDD947ONejh880KwYfvDY8NjwQLhi@MFjXzd9/OCBgmX3xw8eGx4bHhseSFkMv7A6wA8e6FkMP3hseGx4bHggbDH80jLCOoJCAh4oXIxaAh4HHgceBx5IXQy/x4IDP3igdzH84HHgceBx4IHwpSLBb1iZ4AePAw8UMIYfPA48DjyQwRh@0xIGP3gceKCHMfzgceBx4IEoxvBb1jr4wePAA3WM4QePA48DjwMPZDJmUYQfPA480MoYfhZOVk6WTtZOFk9VPeFn/WQBBQ@EM4YfPA48DjyQ0JhlFn7wOPA48EBLY/jB48DjwANBjVmP4QePA48DD5Q1hh88DjwOPA48kNiYlRulGzwuPC48ENwY9Rs8LjwuPJDelHeWePjB48LjwgMNjuEHjwuPC48LDxQ5hh88LjwuPNDmGH7wuPC48LjwQKlj@MHjwuPCA82O4QePC48LjwsPxDuGHzwuPC48LjyQ8pSc@MHjwuPCA1GP4QePC48LjwsPJD6GHzwuPC48EPsYfvC48LhWtJa01rQWtVa1lrXWtVXY4mdpC48LjwuPC48LjwuPC48LjxtWwPjB48LjwuPC48LjwuPC48LjwuOmpbK1MsUyPAIeAY@AR8Aj4BHwCHgEPOKxqMYPHgGPgEfAI@AR8Ah4BDwCHjGsvvGDR8Aj4BHwCHgEPAIeAY@AR0zLdPzgEfAIeAQ8Ah4Bj4BHwCPgEct6Hj94BDwCHgGPgEfAI@AR8Ah4xLbwxw8eAY@AR8Aj4BHwCHgEPAIecVQI@MEj4BHwCHgEPAIeAY@AR8AjrlICP3iEWkOxodpQbqg3FBwqDiVHaQ784BHwCHgEPAIeAY@AR8Aj4BGpOFGdIE/gkfBIeCQ8Eh4Jj4RHwiPhkY8yBj94JDwSHgmPhEfCI@GR8Eh45FDv4AePhEfCI@GR8Eh4JDwSHgmPnAoj/OCR8Eh4JDwSHgmPhEfCI@GRSwWFHzwSHgmPhEfCI@GR8Eh4JDxyK7Xwg0fCI@GR8Eh4JDwSHgmPhEceNRl@8Eh4JDwSHgmPhEfCI@GR8MireMMPHgmPhEfCI@GR8Eh4JDwSHhmqPPxUgcpAdaBCUCWoFFQLKgZVgyUHSw8qCEsRliQsTViisFRhycLShSUMVYb9KQnpFYrDrjrsysOuPuwKxK5C7ErErkbsisQ@SnV6hTqxKxS7SrErFbtasSsWu2qxKxe7erHPEqpeoWTsasauaOyqxq5s7OrGrnDsKseudOyrtK1XqB678rGrH7sCsqsguxKyqyG7IrKrIvsuOewVCsmukuxKya6W7IrJrprsysmunuwKyn5KQXuFmrIrKruqsisru7qyKyy7yrIrLbvast8S3V6hvOzqy67A7CrMrsTsasyuyOyqzK7M7FE63StUml2p2dWaXbHZVZtdudnVm13B2VWcPUval7ZX3Mu82gDVB6hGQHUCqhVQvYBqBrx1A97aAV5RDYHqCFRLoHoC1RSorkC1BWRejYHqDFRroHoD1Ryo7kC1B6o/UA2C6hBUi6B6BNUkqC5BtQmqT1CNguoUVKugegXVLKhuQbULql9QDYPqGFTLoHoG1TSorkG1DapvUI2D6hxU66B6B9U8qO5BtQ@qf1ANhOogVAuhegjVRKguQrURqo9QjYTqJFQroXoJ1UyobkK1E6qfUA2F6ihUS6F6CtVUqK5CtRWqr1CNheosVGuhegvVXKjuQrUXqr9QDYbqMFSLoXoM1WSoLkO1GZ7M/wE)

A direct formula.

Comment: This is nice. I believe you can save 2 bytes with `5*u/4%7-3` instead of `(u-8)*5/4%7`.

Comment: Save 2 more by using the success/error option with `1/(...)` instead of `print ...`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
99R4ḍj`‘ṡ%4ȷ$S€P7ḍ
```

Outputs **1** for members, **0** for non-members.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/SMsjk4Y7erIRHDTMe7lyoanJiu0rwo6Y1AeZA0f///xsaAgA)

#### How it works

```
99R4ḍj`‘ṡ%4ȷ$S€P7ḍ  Main link. Argument: n

99                  Set the return value to 99.
  R                 Range; yield [01, .., 99].
   4ḍ               Test each element in the range for divisibility by 4.
     j`             Join the resulting array, using itself as separator.
                    The result is an array of 9801 Booleans indicating whether the
                    years they represent have leap days.
       ‘            Increment the results, yielding 1 = 365 (mod 7) for non-leap
                    years, 2 = 366 (mod 7) for leap years.
         %4ȷ$       Compute n % 4000.
        ṡ           Take all slices of length n % 4000 of the result to the left.
             S€     Take the sum of each slice.
               P    Take the product of the sums.
                7ḍ  Test for divisibility by 7.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 83 bytes

```python
lambda i:all(c(y)-c(y-i)for y in range(401))
c=lambda n:(5*(n/4)+n%4-n/100+n/400)%7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcvBCsIwEATQe79iL6W7tqGJRIRA@yVeYjW6ELcl9JKvjxEKzmFgYN6W9/cq5xKmW4n@c394YOdjxAUzqVqKKawJMrBA8vJ6otWGqFmm4y4OLyeU0VIvrVUyGq37OrWm9lp@lv/WVOsaqNkSyw48QKfmboCATOUL)

Direct port of [my Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152188).

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

*-35 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan. -2 bytes thanks to Lynn.*

```hs
f i=or[c y==c$y+i|y<-[0..400]]
c n=(5*n#4+n%4-n#100+n#400)%7
(%)=mod
(#)=div
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY27DoIwAEV3vuKGR9LalNQE42L9Ap0ckaEpIo1QGkCFxG@3QtzuPWc4tRoet6bxvoKRXZ9rzFLqeGbmMx94LtI0E6IoAg0ryW5jo4zZJOM22grBlicETfYBSahsuzIgEZWleflWGQuJVrkziHuOl7E/WaQg1wn8CDLU3RsTBWMIVxCu609jVIuhFGt7iRT@q6tG3QfPtXM/)

Using the OEIS PARI program's algorithm.

Comment: `5*(n#4)` can be `5*n#4` also!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 32 bytes

```
iI7*FsM.:hMs.iKiIL4S99*98]K%Q400
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=iI7%2aFsM.%3AhMs.iKiIL4S99%2a98%5DK%25Q400&input=10&test_suite=0&test_suite_input=0%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A11%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A10&debug=0)** (Click "Switch to Test Suite" to verify more test cases at once)

#### How?

Uses a cool [trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/40039/tips-for-golfing-in-pyth/152205#152205) I just added to the "Tips for golfing in Pyth" thread.

```
iI7*FsM.:hMs.iKiIL4S99*98]K%Q400 | Full program. Reads from STDIN, outputs to STDOUT.

                   S99           | Generate the integers in 1 ... 99.
                 L               | For each integer N in that list...
               iI 4              | Check if 4 is invariant over applying GCD with N.
                                 | This is equivalent to checking if 4 | N.
              K                  | Store the result in a variable K.
            .i         *98]K     | And interleave K with the elements of K wrapped
                                 | into a list and repeated 98 times.
           s                     | Flatten.
         hM                      | Increment.
       .:                        | And generate all the substrings...
                           %Q400 | Of length  % 400.
     sM                          | Sum each.
   *F                            | And apply folded product.
iI7                              | Check if 7 is invariant when applied GCD with the
                                 | product (basically check whether 7 | product).
                                 | Implicitly output the appropriate boolean value.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>110</s> 107 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
lambda n,d=date:0in[d(i,1,1).weekday()-d(i+n%400,1,1).weekday()for i in range(1,999)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYxLDoIwEIb3nGI2hlaLgegGEo6gFxAXJZ3qRDsltYnh9BV8bNzov/tf3zDGs@dNSjZ4B0ZHjOQQyA0@xGVm26t2vdHAyrRz25TEByNIVaqS6zvixehRyGKKVrzYluVXYX0AAmIImk8oKlXXtTymIRBHke/Q9RhuTS6zr@FEkk0Gs8gKK0h@7FOvPylk0@Yw3bM3seOO954L9yeZfYSf9PQA)

*-3 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder.*